# On Running Appium script showing error : A new session could not be created

Tags: java, android, appium

Log Flie Attached

> info: --> POST /wd/hub/session {"desiredCapabilities":{"appActivity":"com.google.android.launcher.GEL","appPackage":"com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox","platformName":"Android","deviceName":"","platformVersion":""}}
>
> info: Client User-Agent string: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.1 (Java/1.8.0_77)
>
> info: [debug] Didn't get app but did get Android package, will attempt to launch it on the device
>
> info: [debug] Creating new appium session 13200b99-4982-4ed9-bed4-7dd89bc865dc
>   info: Starting android appium
>   info: [debug] Getting Java version
>   info: Java version is: 1.8.0_77
>   info: [debug] Checking whether adb is present
>   info: [debug] Using adb from

C:\Users\SAMEER_PWS\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe

> warn: No app capability, can't parse package/activity
>   info: [debug] Using fast reset? true
>   info: [debug] Preparing device for session
>   info: [debug] Not checking whether app is present since we are assuming it's already on the device
>
> info: Retrieving device
>   info: [debug] Trying to find a connected android device
>   info: [debug] Getting connected devices...
>   info: [debug] executing cmd:

C:\Users\SAMEER_PWS\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe devices

> info: [debug] 1 device(s) connected
>   info: Found device 0b01aa5a0298ee0e
>   info: [debug] Setting device id to 0b01aa5a0298ee0e
>   info: [debug] Waiting for device to be ready and to respond to shell commands (timeout = 5)
>
> info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\SAMEER_PWS\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 0b01aa5a0298ee0e wait-for-device
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\SAMEER_PWS\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 0b01aa5a0298ee0e shell "echo 'ready'"
>   info: [debug] Starting logcat capture
>   info: [debug] Getting device API level
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\SAMEER_PWS\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 0b01aa5a0298ee0e shell "getprop ro.build.version.sdk"
>   info: [debug] Device is at API Level 23
>   info: Device API level is: 23
>   info: [debug] Extracting strings for language: default
>   info: [debug] Apk doesn't exist locally
>   info: [debug] Could not get strings, but it looks like we had an old strings file anyway, so ignoring
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\SAMEER_PWS\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 0b01aa5a0298ee0e shell "rm -rf /data/local/tmp/strings.json"
>   info: [debug] Not uninstalling app since server not started with --full-reset
>   info: [debug] Skipping install since we launched with a package instead of an app path
>   info: [debug] Forwarding system:4724 to device:4724
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\SAMEER_PWS\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 0b01aa5a0298ee0e forward tcp:4724 tcp:4724
>   info: [debug] Pushing appium bootstrap to device...
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\SAMEER_PWS\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 0b01aa5a0298ee0e push "C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\build\android_bootstrap\AppiumBootstrap.jar" /data/local/tmp/
>   info: [debug] Logcat terminated with code 0, signal null
>   info: [debug] Stopping logcat capture
>   info: [debug] Logcat already stopped
>   info: [debug] Sent shutdown command, waiting for UiAutomator to stop...
>   warn: UiAutomator did not shut down fast enough, calling it gone
>   error: Failed to start an Appium session, err was: Error: Command failed: C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /s /c "C:\Users\SAMEER_PWS\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 0b01aa5a0298ee0e push "C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\build\android_bootstrap\AppiumBootstrap.jar" /data/local/tmp/"
>
> info: [debug] Cleaning up android objects
>   info: [debug] Cleaning up appium session
>   info: [debug] Error: Command failed: C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /s /c "C:\Users\SAMEER_PWS\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 0b01aa5a0298ee0e push "C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\build\android_bootstrap\AppiumBootstrap.jar" /data/local/tmp/"
>
> ```
> at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:751:12)
> at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
> at maybeClose (child_process.js:1016:16)
> at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1088:5)
> ```
>
> info: [debug] Responding to client with error: {"status":33,"value":{"message":"A new session could not be created.

(Original error: Command failed: C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /s /c \"C:\Users\SAMEER_PWS\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 0b01aa5a0298ee0e push \"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Appium\\node_modules\\appium\\build\\android_bootstrap\\AppiumBootstrap.jar\" /data/local/tmp/\"\n)","killed":false,"code":1,"signal":null,"cmd":"C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /s /c \"C:\Users\SAMEER_PWS\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 0b01aa5a0298ee0e push \"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Appium\\node_modules\\appium\\build\\android_bootstrap\\AppiumBootstrap.jar\" /data/local/tmp/\"","origValue":"Command failed: C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /s /c \"C:\Users\SAMEER_PWS\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 0b01aa5a0298ee0e push \"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Appium\\node_modules\\appium\\build\\android_bootstrap\\AppiumBootstrap.jar\" /data/local/tmp/\"\n"},"sessionId":null}

> info: <-- POST /wd/hub/session 500 12924.220 ms - 1039

Comment: DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();  caps.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, "Android");caps.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_VERSION, "");caps.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "");
caps.setCapability("appActivity","com.google.android.launcher.GEL");
caps.setCapability("appPackage",com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox");URL url = new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub");
  AndroidDriver<WebElement> driver1 = new AndroidDriver<WebElement>(url, caps);
  driver1.findElement(By.name("Calculator")).click();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the path to your .apk file:

```
capabilities.setCapability("app", "path to apk");
```

Comment: we can open the app by defining activity name & Package name too !!

the problem was server was not started properly

so for resolution i used the command in the command promopt


adb  kill-server

adb start- server

to start the server again. & then it worked.